# Spring - Does RedirectAttributes make aware the Controller that we are going to redirect?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, post, dependency-injection

I'm trying to figure out which is the correct way of dealing with the Post/Redirect/Get design pattern in Spring MVC. Spring 4.0.x documentation reports:

> The controller should not really care about how the response gets handled. In general it should operate only in terms of view names that **have been injected** into it.

and

> As with the `redirect:` prefix, if the view name with the `forward:` prefix is injected into the controller, the controller does not detect that anything special is happening in terms of handling the response.

By reading this, it seems that the correct way of handling redirects is to inject the logical view name `redirect:somewhere` into the Controller, so that the handler method won't notice that we are actually implementing the PRG pattern (or, in general, that we are performing a redirect for whatever reason).

If we assume that some non-primitive types have been added as model attributes, it sounds reasonable to use `RedirectAttributes` to store as flash attributes those data that we want to survive to the redirect. Nevertheless, at this point we effectively let the Controller know that we are going to redirect.

Hence, what is the reason to inject the view name in the first place? More in general, does it make sense to add another level of indirection by injecting the logical view names as external dependencies?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this statement is absolutely out of date.

It was originally written for [Spring 1.2.4](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.4/reference/mvc.html#d0e10010), even before Spring got annotations.

That's how controller declaration with injected view names looked at that time:

```
<bean name="/editaccount.form" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleFormController">
    <property name="formView"><value>account</value></property>
    <property name="successView"><value>account-created</value></property>
    <property name="commandName"><value>Account</value></property>
    <property name="commandClass"><value>samples.Account</value></property>
</bean>
```

Design of Spring MVC has changed dramatically since then, therefore I don't think that this recommendation is still valid now.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I took that sentences from the current documentation. Anyhow, are you suggesting that the best practice is to actually hard-code view names into the handler methods and to make them aware we are going to redirect?

Comment: I think that hardcoding view names (including redirects) is perfectly valid. There is no need to introduce extra complexity without any real reason.